# Dynamic query - how to do it

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am using the way to build dynamic queries (create a generic mechanism for MongoDB) from: https://michaelscodingspot.com/dynamic-queries/, but somehow it is not working. Below is the code:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(IQueryable<T> query, string propertyToFilter, string value)
  {
     ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
     MemberExpression memberAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, propertyToFilter);
     ConstantExpression exprRight = Expression.Constant(value);
     BinaryExpression equalExpr = Expression.Equal(memberAccess, exprRight);
     Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalExpr, parameterExpression);

     return query.Where(lambda);
  }
```

The error I received is: System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'itemName')'

When I am using the normal way: `query.where(p => p.GroupId == value)` everything is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I figure out it:
It is missing the propertyToFilter in the ParameterException

```
 public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(IMongoQueryable<T> query, string propertyToFilter, string value)
  {
     ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), propertyToFilter);
     MemberExpression memberAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, propertyToFilter);
     ConstantExpression exprRight = Expression.Constant(value);
     BinaryExpression equalExpr = Expression.Equal(memberAccess, exprRight);
     Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalExpr, parameterExpression);

     return query.Where(lambda);
  }
```